# Sequence converging uniformly on a closed interval

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Prove that $x/n→ 0$ uniformly, as $n→ \infty$, on any closed interval $[a,b]$.

attempt:  Then let $\epsilon > 0$, then there is $N \in N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$.
Let M = max{a,b} for all x in [a,b]. And choose $N > \frac{|x|}{\epsilon}$ so that $|\frac{x}{n}| \leq \frac{M}{n} \leq \frac{M}{N} = \epsilon$.

I am not sure if this is fine. Can someone please help me? any suggestion would be really appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: You can't suppose that the thing you're trying to prove is true at the start.

Comment: that was a typo. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$\left|\frac{x}{n}-0\right| \leqslant \frac{max(|b|,|a|)}{n}$$

Comment: So we just need to add the absolute values? Then everything is the same?

Comment: Can you show the RHS can be made smaller than $\epsilon$ if $n$ is large enough, independent of $x$?

Comment: So choosing $N = M/\epsilon$ + constant?

Comment: ... and, yes, we want absolute values.  If $x \in [a,b] = [-10,5]$ then is $|x| < max(-10,5)$ as you suggested?

Comment: So when explaining why we choose such N we can say what you said that the RHS can be made smaller than $\epsilon$ if $n$ is large enough, else it would not work.

Comment: Yes RHS is smaller than $\epsilon$ if $n > N(\epsilon) > max(|a|,|b|)/\epsilon$ where $N(\epsilon)$ does not depend on $x$.